# Orgmode: How to refresh Local Org Setup (C-c C-c) from keybinding?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I want to change `org-hide-emphasis-markers` variable in a mid of editing emphasized words (e.g. bold, italics, inline code). Basically I want keybinding for toggling (hide/show) emphasis markers (`~_*=`).

**Problem:** after changing value in `org-hide-emphasis-markers`, it needs pressing `C-c` `C-c` at the top level, in order to change applies.

**Question:** How to execute `(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)` from anywhere in the buffer (i.e. without moving my cursor, or without extending/collapsing my subheadings) such that it's behavior is same as `C-c` `C-c`-ing at the top. Maybe perhaps adding some arguments?

---

PS.: I've seen great package [org-appear](https://github.com/awth13/org-appear). However, It's automatic feature disrupts my flow. Plus, I want to do it manually.

PS: also `M-x` `org-mode` (or `org-mode-restart`) collapses my current subheading due to my (`#+STARTUP: show2levels`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org-mode uses font-lock to show the emphasis markers. So you can just 'reapply' the fontification using `font-lock-update`.

You could bind the following command to your preferred keybinding

```lisp
(defun org-toggle-emphasis-markers ()
  (interactive)
  (setq org-hide-emphasis-markers (not org-hide-emphasis-markers))
  (font-lock-update))
```